# Error when running "vino-preferences" on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ssh, 15.10, remote-desktop, remote-access, vino

I'm trying to configure and enable remote login on an Ubuntu 15.10 machine by connecting to it using ssh from Ubuntu 14 machine.

On Ubuntu 15.10 machine, I've installed `vino` using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install vino
```

However when I try to run:

```
vino-preferences
```

I get the following error:

```
$ sudo vino-preferences
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket:
  No suchfile or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(vino-preferences:8267): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

How can I solve this?

Please, whoever wants to suggest something, please use simple words and detailed steps; as I am so shallow in all Linux things.

Note: *that ubuntu-desktop is not installed yet on the destination server (the Ubuntu 15)... I don't know if this matters!*

Comment: Are you running `vino-preferences` through SSH?

Comment: If so, then this is normal. If you want to run graphical applications through SSH, you have to enable X11 forwarding in SSH (use SSH with the `-X` flag).

Comment: Thank Raju... I've tried ssh -X [ip address] ... then tried the vino-preferences command ... but same error

Comment: Do you have X-Forwarding enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? The line should look like `X11Forwarding yes`

Comment: if you are asking about the server side (the Ubuntu 15), then yes it is enabled and I've restarted ssh using:    sudo service ssh restart    ... and even I restarted the whole server .... but nothing changed ... same error

Comment: Does the server have a GUI installed?

Comment: No not yet ... should I install it?

Comment: If you want to run graphical apps - yes. But remember that it will just slow down your server and you are better off using `dconf` commands to control vino through the CLI. Also, vino *itself* needs a GUI to exist - else, what would the VNC broadcast?